# Formalin fallen out of solution

Tags: solubility, solutions

Is there a way to bring back into solution a bottle of formalin that has crystallized? The bottle has been stored for several years at room temperature.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't have the knowledge to answer this, but if the answerer feels this lacks some information, I'd be happy if they comment.

Answer (score 2):

The 'crystals' are polyformaldehyde, more commonly called paraformaldehyde.

Heat it up, with some base catalyst.